# C# if statement within a range

Tags: c#

I need my if statement to return an image if it is within a range. the current code does not work

```
  if (Int32.Parse(Domain_OSUMC_IT_CHECKBOX.Text.Trim()) == 1)
            {
                Domain_green_Check.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (Int32.Parse(XP_OSUWMC_IT_LBL.Text.Trim()) >= 1 && <=.9)
        {
            Domain_green_Check.Visible = true;
```

This is where im having the trouble

```
else if (Int32.Parse(XP_OSUWMC_IT_LBL.Text.Trim()) >= 1 && <=.9)
```

I need to make the image domain_green_check visible if another label Domain_OSUMC_IT_CHCEKBOX is between the values of .9 and 1

Comment: `<.9` with `Int` comparison ... ummm not going to work

Comment: .9 is not an int. How can something be less than .9 and greater than 1? And you need something on the left of the `<`.

Comment: There are several reasons why that line is incorrect. Does the compiler generate any errors that help give you a clue?

Comment: First fix your c# syntax `Int32.Parse(XP_OSUWMC_IT_LBL.Text.Trim()) > 1 and <.9`.  what is `and`? What do you compare with `<.9`? (and your logic is similar to x>1 && x<0 which is always false)

Comment: OK, this is why I asked the question. I need to make the image domain_green_check visible if another label Domain_OSUMC_IT_CHCEKBOX is between the values of .9 and 1 Please be constructive in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your syntax and conert the string to `decimal`

```
decimal val = decimal.Parse(XP_OSUWMC_IT_LBL.Text.Trim());
else if (val > .9 && val < 1) //though this condition makes nosense since it will never evaluate to TRUE
```